# Ignore duplicate servlet mappings in web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

We are getting an error with duplicate servlet mappings in web.xml for tomcat. We want to allow duplicate servlet mappings without tomcat to falling all over its self

We removed the duplicate entry and did not have a problem anymore. However we have no way currently to tell if a developer checked in a web.xml with duplicate entries so we don't want to break production.

Comment: If you let such an easily avoidable mistake go to production and you are fine with it, you have a whole different problem. There's a reason the error exists. What if the duplicate mapping point to different servlets?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent your software from warning you about potentially misleading behaviour?

Comment: So I am guessing neither of you know how to disable that checking.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the OP would still want the warning in catalina.out, but would still want Tomcat to continue to load the servlets successfully.

I've seen Tomcat systems with dozens of .war files deployed to them, and you wouldn't want the entire server to go down because just one of those .war files was deployed incorrectly.